# In Django how to getbinary field data from POST form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have one HTML file, where I am using one image upload button. Now this image is stored in the MySql database as Blob. I need to get or read this image data somehow in Django through post method. Can anyone please help how to do?

Icon is defined like :

```
icon = models.BinaryField(null=True)
```

My Html:

```
 <input type="file" id="toolicon" accept="image/*" data-type='image'  >
<button id="OpenImgUpload" style="margin-left: 100px">Image Upload</button>
```

In JQuery:

```
$('#OpenImgUpload').click(function(){ $('#toolicon').trigger('click'); });
```

Image:

[image: Html look]

Now I want to get this file as Binary Field data. Till now I have used :

```
tool_icon = request.POST('toolicon', '')
tool_icon = request.POST.get('toolicon', '')
tool_icon = base64.b64encode('toolicon', '')
```

Nothing works ... Can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded files are contained in [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) with the key corresponding to the `name` attribute on the input element.

So you should add a `name` attribute to your input:

```
<input type="file" name="toolicon" ...
```

And then access the data using `request.FILES`:

```
tool_icon = request.FILES.get('toolicon', '')
```

The request must have a content type of `multipart/form-data` which you should set on your form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...
```

Comment: Hi, It's showing multiValueDictKey error on toolicon

Comment: Did you set your form to `multipart/form-data`? If the form doesn't contain an icon then you'll need to use the `FILES.get()` method - I have updated the answer

Comment: Now its showing 'string argument without an encoding'. I want the image as binary field. Do I need any encoding?

Comment: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform2">
                                              <label for="toolicon" class="col-1 col-form-label text-right" style="margin-left:15px">ToolIcon</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="toolicon" accept="image/*" data-type='image'>   that is my html now

Comment: I don't think your form is posting the binary data correctly. Check in your browser's network panel. Also shouldn't your Image Upload button submit the form? e.g. `$('#OpenImgUpload').click(function(){ $('#formId')[0].trigger('submit'); });`

Comment: No, I have a signup form for example, name, Empid, etc, plus icon to upload photo. Now At last there is one button save , onclick which one user will be created.So basically I want to upload image as when clicking final save it will go to my create_user method